# Unable to select any option of HTML select list in android tv box

Tags: android, webview, selectlist, tvbox

Currently working on an app running in android tv box, the problem is, HTML select list is not working properly in the webview. Unable to select any option

The box brand is Vuuv

Comment: Do you have any code for us?

Comment: Even the default select list of the browser is not working...We tried at [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)...not working